# How to use document.getElementsByTagName in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, getelementsbytagname

I was using the following code without Backbone.js and it was working - preventing the ghost images from appearing when trying to drag the image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').attr('draggable', false);
document.getElementsByTagName('img').draggable = false;
});
```

Now I'm learning backbone.js and trying to implement it in the Views, this is how it looks:

```
function noDrag () {
        $(that.el).find('img').attr('draggable', false);
        document.getElementsByTagName('img').draggable = false;
    }

    noDrag();
```

It doesn't work.

I know that the key to making this work is getting the part enter code here`document.getElementsByTagName('img').draggable = false;` to work. What's wrong with my code?

Here goes the full code:

```
    window.dolnyPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'div',
    className : 'dolnyPanel-menu-view',
    initialize : function() {
        var that = this;
        // tu wybierz template z templates/main.tpl
        this.template = _.template($("#dolnyPanel-view").html());     
        return this;
    },
    events : {

    },
    render : function() {
        var that = this;       
        $(this.el).html(this.template());  
       $(this.el).find('#panel-view').carousel({
         interval: 3000
         });


        var BandCount;

        $.post('api/getBandsCount.php', function(data) {

            BandCount=data;
        });



         var items = getItems(BandCount);
        $(this.el).find('.carousel-inner').html($(items));
        $(this.el).find('.item').first().addClass('active');




         function getItems(BandCount) {
           // console.log(BandCount);
            var allItems = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= BandCount; i++) {
                var items = '';
                for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    if (i <= BandCount) {
                        items += getImageItem(i);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                allItems += '<div class="item"><div class="row">' + items + '</div></div>';
            }
        return allItems; 
        }

        function getImageItem(id) {
        var item = '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 artist-col biography-artist-col"><a href="#x" bandId="'+id+'">';

        var src = 'LEKSYKON';

        $.post('api/getAwatar.php', {id: id}, function(data) {

            src = src + data.path;

        }, "json");
        item += '<img src="' + src + '" alt="Image" class="img-responsive artist"></a></div>';
        return item;
    }

        function noDrag () {
            $(that.el).find('img').attr('draggable', false);
            document.getElementsByTagName('img').draggable = false;
        }

        noDrag();


        return this;
    }


});
```

**UPDATE:** thank you for all the answers, it turned out that it's not working because the whole view doesn't work. The thread could be closed now not to mistake anybody.

Comment: please add View full code src

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of DOM elements, so you'd need to apply the attribute change to every element rather than to the collection itself.

As you're using jQuery already, you don't need to use `document.getElementsByTagName` - you can create another jQuery selection.

In fact, that's exactly what you are doing in your first, working example - `document.getElementsByTagName` is not doing anything there.

You can use jQuery's `prop` method to reliably change a toggleable attribute for all elements in a selection.

```
$('img').prop('draggable', false);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for an discussion of `prop` vs `attr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//this will get the first img element 
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
//setting value of attribute
element.setAttribute("draggable", false);
```

Comment: are you getting any element in `var element`?